# NGINX regex for tree in URL structure

Tags: regex, nginx

On NGINX, I'm trying to configure a location that captures everything below the /payments branch in the URL tree, but nothing else:

```
/payments
/payments/
/payments/anything
/payments/anything/everything
```

I tried the following, but it does not work:

```
location ^~ /payments(?:/.*)?$ {
    deny all;
}
```

Works fine in [standard regex tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html), but not on an [NGINX regex tester](https://nginx.viraptor.info/) or on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: the modifier should have been ~ instead of ^~.